# High Memory Usage when python multiprocessing run in Windows

Tags: python, performance, memory, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

The code down below is a contrived example that simulates an actual problem I have that uses multiprocessing to speed up the code. The code is run on `Windows 10 64-bit OS`, `python 3.7.5`, and `ipython 7.9.0`

---

the transformation functions(these functions will be used to transform arrays in `main()`)

```
from itertools import product
from functools import partial

from numba import njit, prange
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel= True)
def transform_array_c(data, n):

    ar_len= len(data)

    sec_max1= np.empty(ar_len, dtype = data.dtype)
    sec_max2= np.empty(ar_len, dtype = data.dtype)

    for i in prange(n-1):
        sec_max1[i]= np.nan

    for sec in prange(ar_len//n):
        s2_max= data[n*sec+ n-1]
        s1_max= data[n*sec+ n]

        for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            if data[n*sec+i] > s2_max:
                s2_max= data[n*sec+i]
            sec_max2[n*sec+i]= s2_max

        sec_max1[n*sec+ n-1]= sec_max2[n*sec]

        for i in range(n-1):
            if n*sec+n+i < ar_len:
                if data[n*sec+n+i] > s1_max:
                    s1_max= data[n*sec+n+i]
                sec_max1[n*sec+n+i]= max(s1_max, sec_max2[n*sec+i+1])

            else:
                break

    return sec_max1  

@njit(error_model= 'numpy', cache= True)
def rt_mean_sq_dev(array1, array2, n):
    msd_temp = np.empty(array1.shape[0])

    K = array2[n-1]

    rs_x= array1[0] - K
    rs_xsq = rs_x *rs_x

    msd_temp[0] = np.nan

    for i in range(1,n):
        rs_x += array1[i] - K
        rs_xsq += np.square(array1[i] - K)
        msd_temp[i] = np.nan

    y_i = array2[n-1] - K
    msd_temp[n-1] = np.sqrt(max(y_i*y_i + (rs_xsq - 2*y_i*rs_x)/n, 0))

    for i in range(n, array1.shape[0]):
        rs_x = array1[i] - array1[i-n]+ rs_x
        rs_xsq = np.square(array1[i] - K) - np.square(array1[i-n] - K) + rs_xsq
        y_i = array2[i] - K

        msd_temp[i] = np.sqrt(max(y_i*y_i + (rs_xsq - 2*y_i*rs_x)/n, 0))

    return msd_temp 

@njit(cache= True)
def transform_array_a(data, n):
    result = np.empty(data.shape[0], dtype= data.dtype)
    alpharev = 1. - 2 / (n + 1)
    alpharev_exp = alpharev

    e = data[0]
    w = 1.

    if n == 2: result[0] = e
    else:result[0] = np.nan

    for i in range(1, data.shape[0]):
        w += alpharev_exp
        e = e*alpharev + data[i]

        if i > n -3:result[i] = e / w
        else:result[i] = np.nan

        if alpharev_exp > 3e-307:alpharev_exp*= alpharev
        else:alpharev_exp=0.

    return result
```

---

The multiprocessing part

```
def func(tup, data):    #<-------------the function to be run among all 
    a_temp= a[tup[2][0]]

    idx1 = a_temp > a[tup[2][1]]
    idx2= a_temp < b[(tup[2][1], tup[1][1])]

    c_final = c[tup[0][1]][idx1 | idx2]
    data_final= data[idx1 | idx2]

    return (tup[0][0], tup[1][0], *tup[2]), c_final[-1] - data_final[-1]

def setup(a_dict, b_dict, c_dict):    #initialize the shared dictionaries
    global a,b,c
    a,b,c = a_dict, b_dict, c_dict

def main(a_arr, b_arr, c_arr, common_len):
    np.random.seed(0)
    data_array= np.random.normal(loc= 24004, scale=500, size= common_len)

    a_size = a_arr[-1] + 1
    b_size = len(b_arr)
    c_size = len(c_arr)

    loop_combo = product(enumerate(c_arr),
                         enumerate(b_arr),
                         (n_tup for n_tup in product(np.arange(1,a_arr[-1]), a_arr) if n_tup[1] > n_tup[0])
                         )
    result = np.zeros((c_size, b_size, a_size -1 ,a_size), dtype = np.float32) 

    ###################################################
    #This part simulates the heavy-computation in the actual problem

    a= {}
    b= {}
    c= {}

    for i in range(1, a_arr[-1]+1):

        a[i]= transform_array_a(data_array, i)
        if i in a_arr:
            for j in b_arr:
                b[(i,j)]= rt_mean_sq_dev(data_array, a[i], i)/data_array *j


    for i in c_arr:
        c[i]= transform_array_c(data_array, i)

    ###################################################    
    with mp.Pool(processes= mp.cpu_count() - 1,
                 initializer= setup,
                 initargs= [a,b,c]
                 ) as pool:
        mp_res= pool.imap_unordered(partial(func, data= data_array),
                                    loop_combo
                                    )

        for item in mp_res:
            result[item[0]] =item[1]


    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()

    a_arr= np.arange(2,44,2)
    b_arr= np.arange(0.4,0.8, 0.20)
    c_arr= np.arange(2,42,10)
    common_len= 440000

    final_res= main(a_arr, b_arr, c_arr, common_len)
```

For performance reasons, multiple shared "read only" dictionaries are used among all processes to reduce the redundant computations(in the actual problem, the total computation time is reduced by 40% after using shared dictionaries among all the processes). However, The ram usage becomes absurdly higher after using shared dictionaries in my actual problem; memory usage in my 6C/12T Windows computer goes from (8.2GB peak, 5.0GB idle) to (23.9GB peak, 5.0GB idle), a little too high of a cost to pay in order to gain 40% speed up.

Is the high ram usage unavoidable when using multiple shared data among processes is a must? What can be done to my code in order to make it as fast as possible while using as low memory as possible?

Thank you in advance

---

Note: I tried using `imap_unordered()` instead of `map` because I heard it is supposed to reduce the memory usage when the input iterable is large, but I honestly can't see an improvement in the ram usage. Maybe I have done something wrong here?

---

EDIT: Due to the feedback in the answers, I have already changed the heavy computation part of the code such that it looks less dummy and resembles the computation in the actual problem.

Comment: You might be able to reduce memory consumption by using [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) arrays.

Comment: @martineau in what part of my script do you think it is the best place to use `numpy.memmap` arrays?

Comment: Replace the 'multiple shared "read only" dictionaries' with them.

Comment: @martineau I will give it a shot, hopefully the memory usage can be reduced without losing too many performance gain in the memory-speedup trade-off.

Comment: Memory-mapping can be quite fast because at the lowest levels the OS's support for them is utilized.

Comment: @martineau That's awesome. From what I saw in [the example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) it seems it uses some sort of files to handle the stored arrays. Hopefully they can handle 3-4 50MB shared arrays.

Comment: That's actually not all that much, esp if you have a lot of ram. Even if you don't have tons of it, memory-mapped files are handled by the OS's own page-fault handling mechanisms, which are usually highly-optimized. Here's some [additional information](https://pymotw.com/3/mmap/index.html) about them.

Comment: Just noticed that a new [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) class was added in Python 3.8 — so that's another possibility. There's even a example in the documentation that "demonstrates a practical use of the `SharedMemory` class with NumPy arrays".

Comment: @martineau good to know there is a well documented solution to this kind of problem in python 3.8. Can‘t wait to upgrade to 3.8 next month because for the moment I can’t upgrade it just yet.

Comment: @martineau With all due respect, the O/P does not actively use any step, that would justify the costs of ( NUMA-expensive and any-to-any cross-core coordinated ) sharing of any published data-structure above. The solution of the HPC / computing problems is not in finding an easy way to pick the lowest-hanging-fruit ( by typing a cosy syntax-constructor that seems simple, is legal, yet is also **very inefficient** during run-time ), but rather in designing code tailor-made to achieving the very opposite - **to achieve the ultimate performance in run-time**. This is the problem solving step.

Comment: @user3666197: Likewise, with all due respect, I'm just continuing to address the titular question — which is a valid one, and is likely why most folks will even look at this question.

Comment: @mathguy I completely forgot to come back to this, are you still open to/looking for answers?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes, I am still looking for answer(s) with code examples.

Comment: @mathguy Great, I’ll come back and take a look tomorrow! Do you think it might be worth creating a chat room for this question, since there is probably going to be a good amount of discussion?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes this will definitely be helpful.

Comment: @mathguy Okay, are you currently making one or should I do it?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I can make one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202179/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-mathguy).

Comment: @mathguy Nevermind, don’t bother! SO finally gave me the option to do so automatically.

Answer (score 2):

> ## High Memory Usage when manipulating *shared dictionaries* in python `multiprocessing` run in Windows

It is fair to demystify a bit the problem, before we move into details - there are **no *shared dictionaries*** in the original code, the less they get ***manipulated*** ( yes, each of the `a,b,c` did get "assigned" to a reference to the `dict_a, dict_b, dict_c` yet none of them is ***shared***, but just get replicated as the **`multiprocessing`** does in Windows-class O/S-es. No writes "into" `dict`-s ( just non-destructive reads-from either of their replicas )

Similarly, the `np.memmap()`-s are possible to put some part of the originally proposed data onto disk-space ( at a cost of doing so + bearing some ( latency-masked ) random-reads latency of `~ 10 [ms]` instead of `~ 0.5 [ns]` if smart-aligned vectorised memory-patterns were designed into the performance hot-spot ) yet no dramatic change-of-paradigm ought be expected here, as the "external iterator" almost avoids any smart-aligned cache re-uses

> **Q** : ***What can be done** to my code in order to make it as fast as possible while using as low memory as possible?*

The first sin was in using an **`8B`**-`int64` to store one plain Bbit ( no Qbits here yet ~ All salutes to Burnaby Quantum R&D Teams )

```
for i in c_arr:                                    # ~~ np.arange( 2, 42, 10 )
     np.random.seed( i )                           # ~ yields a deterministic state
     c[i] = np.random.poisson( size = common_len ) # ~ 440.000 int64-s with {0|1}
```

This took **`6`** (processes) x **`440000`** x **`8B ~ 0.021 GB`** "smuggled" in all copies of dictionary **`c`**, whereas each and every such value is deterministically known and could be generated ALAP inside a respective target process, by just knowing the value of `i` ( indeed no need to pre-generate and many-times replicate `~ 0.021 GB` of data )

So far, the Windows-class O/S [lack an `os.fork()` and thus do a python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) full-copy ( yes, RAM ..., yes, TIME ) of as many replicated python-interpreter sessions ( plus importing the main module ) as was requested, in `multiprocessing` for process-based separation ( doing that for avoiding a GIL-lock ordered, pure-`[SERIAL]`, code execution )

---

### The Best Next Step:
re-factor the code
for both efficiency and performance

The best next step - refactor the code, so as to minimise a "shallow" ( and expensive ) use of the 6-processes but "externally"-commanded by a central iterator ( **the `loop_combo` "dictator"** with ~ 18522 items to repeat the call to a "remotely-dispatched" **`func( tup, data )`** so as to fetch a simple "DMA-tuple"-`( (x,y,z), value )` to store one `value` into a central process **`result`**-`float32`-array ).

Try to increase the computing "density" - so try to re-factor the code by a divide-and-conquer manner ( i.e., that each of the `mp.pool`-processes computes in one smooth block some remarkably sized, dedicated sub-space of the parameter-space covered ( here iteratively "from ouside" ) and may easily reduce the returned blocks of results. Performance will only improve by doing this ( best without any form of expensive sharing ).

This re-factoring will avoid parameter `pickle`/`unpickle`-costs ( add-on overheads - both the one-time ( in passing the unique parameter-set values ) and the repetitive ( in about a ~ 18522-times executed repetitive memory-allocation, buildup and `pickle`/`unpickle`-costs of an `np.arange( 440000 )` due to a poor call-signature design / engineering )

All these steps will improve your processing efficiency and reduce the there unnecessary RAM-allocations.

Comment: The first sin was due to the fact that I was trying to generate a bunch of arrays as computationally expensive as the actual array_transformation function I use in the actual problem where I use different weighted moving averages in a,b,c. The i value in this contrived problem corresponds to the `moving_window_size` because a slight difference in `i`( `moving_window_size` ) will lead to a complete different array. Maybe I should rewrite this part in my post to truly reflect what the array_transformation function does.

Comment: @mathguy Please do update your code if you can, I would love to take a look at this later :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile greatly appreciate the help from you guys

Comment: Pretty good answer, although a bit hard to digest. A brief summary at the end would be a great addition.

Comment: I'm still confused about "( i.e., that each of the `mp.pool`-processes computes in one smooth block some remarkably sized, dedicated sub-space of the parameter-space covered......)" From what I understand, it seems I need to make each worker in `mp.pool` computes exactly one `smooth` block of parameter subspace( so 6 `smooth` blocks in total). Then how can I make `mp.pool` do that? Every time I see guidelines in multiprocessing just tells me to throw the function and iterable in and call it a day. I am struggling to find clear examples about making manual smooth block to throw into `mp.pool`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for both your compliment and advice. Small World again here. FORTRAN IV manual was my 2nd Bible ( The 1st was the HP-67 one - a very educational book, not just about programming, it was full of stories about design-thinking - from Moon Lander simulator ( sure, not as complex as the AGC-ferrite-ROM magic flewn to the Mare Tranquillitatis inside the Eagle ). OMG, the time is so fast. Anyway, thank you for reminding me to those lovely days, Martin. **Let me wish you all the best, Man :o)**